# Replace all occurrences of more than one whilespace character with a single one

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

Input:

```
Rammar  Narayana raja  Rani.
```

Output:

```
Rammar Narayana raja Rani.
```

In C# code I oculd do this:

```
    while (name.Contains("  "))
    {
        name = name.Replace("  ", " ");
    }
```

That replaces the double with single spaces and that should store in same variable. But here I want to replace more than one whitespace in string to one whitespace, for all occurance. How can I do that in Oracle SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('aa      b     cc     d  e f ', '( ){2,}', ' ')
FROM DUAL;
```

For details, see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm); it's one of the examples.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ( 'Rammar    Narayana   raja    Rani.', '  +', ' ' )
FROM   DUAL;
```

or if you want to replace any white spaces then:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ( 'Rammar    Narayana   raja    Rani.', '\s+', ' ' )
FROM   DUAL;
```